# ListPreference Dropdown

Tags: android

I am using preference screen in Tabhost,so it was displaying the preference background white in order to fix it I used a theme which changed background color to black 
but the same is appled to the listprefernce dropdown list as well and I can't see any option

as idiotic question as it sounds it has been killing me for hours
thanks in advance